# What does the .= operator mean in PHP?

Tags: php, operators, equals

I have a variable that is being defined as

```
$var .= "value";
```

How does the use of the dot equal function?

Comment: Used to append value in variable which already contains some value...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's the concatenating assignment operator. It works similarly to:

```
$var = $var . "value";
```

`$x .=` differs from `$x = $x .` in that the former is in-place, but the latter re-assigns `$x`.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure why there was a down vote either. This is also backed by http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Both do re-assign `$x`.

Comment: @m93a: Can you link to documentation?

Comment: @Blender OK, you're right, they don't. The `$x .=` performs [~2 times faster](http://michal.grno.cz/trash/assignment.php) than `$x = $x .` but the spec isn't really verbose on this matter.

Comment: yes but only for strings - i just spent fuc*** hours wondering why the hell my float was getting turned into a freaking string! Apparently this damn operator will cast your damn floats to strings.. I am so annoyed right now!

Comment: Do you mean that `$x = "Hi"; $pi = 3.14; $x .= $pi;` changes `$pi`?!

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I imagine you know the answer 4 years later, but for posterity: No, in your example, $x .= $pi would not change $pi to a string. However, $pi .= $x would change $pi to a string, (specifically a string that equals $pi .$x or "3.14Hi").

Answer (score 27):

This is for concatenation

```
$var  = "test";
$var .= "value";

echo $var; // this will give you testvalue
```

Answer (score 20):

the "`.`" operator is the string concatenation operator. and "`.=`" will concatenate strings.

**Example:**

```
$var = 1;
$var .= 20;
```

**This is same as:**

```
$var = 1 . 20;
```

the "`.=`" operator is a string operator, it first converts the values to strings; and since "`.`" means **concatenate / append**, the result is the string "`120`".

Answer (score -1):

In very plain language, what happens is that whatever is stored in each variable is converted to a string and then each string is placed into a final variable that includes each value of each variable put together.

I use this to generate a random variable of alpha numeric and special characters.  Example below:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 64) {
    $characters = '0123456789-!@#$%^*()?:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = mb_strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

then to get the value of $randomString I assign a variable to the function like so

```
$key = generateRandomString();
echo $key;
```

What this does is pick a random character from any of the characters in the $characters variable.  Then .= puts the result of each of these random "picks" together, in a new variable that has 64 random picks from the $characters string group called $randomString.