# php how to strip last character from string in php

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to strip the last `,` from a string but do not succeed in it.
I need a string like this: `2,3,4`
But when trying to strip the last `,` i get as ouput: `234` instead of `2,3,4`

```
$alldays = array('2','3','4');

foreach($alldays as $day) {
    $string = $day.',';
    $string_without_last_comma = substr($string, 0, -1);
    echo $string; // output: 2,3,4,
    echo $string_without_last_comma; // output: 234 ( should be 2,3,4)

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hint: [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: `$string` only exists inside the loop, so you're adding the comma, and removing at next line. Wouldn't `implode` be a much better solution?

Comment: Yes, `implode` exists, but for more general cases: Don’t _add_ the extra comma in the first place! That becomes easier, if you turn the logic around - don’t add a comma _after_ each item, but _before_. Then you only have to handle the case of the first item - which you can then easily do, by checking if `$string` is still empty. If it is, then you are about to add the first item to it, and therefor don’t need to add a comma before it.

Comment: I agree. `implode` fixes this problem. thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer

Use [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```php
<?php
$alldays = array('2','3','4');
$string = implode(',', $alldays);
echo $string;
```

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLJTEnJyWxsljBViGxqCixUkPdSF1H3RiITdQ1rblUikuKMvPSgbKZuQU5@SmpGkAZHQWYLqCK1OSMfAWoMuv//wE)</sup>

#### Debug

Let's walk though the code

```
<?php
// Define alldays
$alldays = array('2','3','4');

// For each day
foreach($alldays as $day) {

    // Create(=) a string, add $day and a comma
    $string = $day.',';

    // Remove the last char from $string and save ('NOT ADD') in $string_without_last_comma
    $string_without_last_comma = substr($string, 0, -1);

    // Show string
    echo $string;

    // Show string with last char
    echo $string_without_last_comma;
}

// String here is the last char?
echo $string;
```

So the loop does show all those values, but they're not being added to eachother, only shown once per loop iteration.

Recap;

1. Since you're doing `$string = $day.',';` you're overriding `$string` every loop
2. Same for `$string_without_last_comma`; you're not appending anything, only overriding
3. `implode()` would give the desired result

#### Fixed original code

**Note**: Pure for learning purposes, I'll still recommend [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Without the use of `implode()`, my guess is that you're trying to do something like this;

```php
<?php

// Define alldays
$alldays = array('2','3','4');

// Create empty string
$string = '';

// For each day
foreach($alldays as $day) {

    // Add(.=) $day and a comma
    $string .= $day . ',';

    // Keep doing this logic for all the $day's in $alldays
}

// Now $string contains 2,3,4,
// So here we can create $string_without_last_comma by removing the last char
$string_without_last_comma = substr($string, 0, -1);

// Show result
echo $string_without_last_comma;
```

Here we

1. Create an empty string
2. Loop through all the days
3. [Add (`.=`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846570/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-php/14846599) day to `$string` and add a comma
4. After the loop, we can remove the last comma
5. Show the result

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDLasMwELzrK@YQkANu0ia5JaaUll4KveQDwkbeRAJbMpLSYEq/3ZUfyTECoWFnZ3ZWjW66bvfa6EaI5RIffDKWQVVVUhvEbAIoQN5Tm8mVzOU63Y2cbwfFu2eKDK6b2CJEb@xZzMY3qaQcuz6dB5PSSG7i5HyPs7s7BcwSmONXCKSTBG9lmS2K@VAH2RIE5eqaBv7mvyhGfoGUaHvXfjE3KF3fEbUJqNzZKKSp/V6pxINKBhiLWwbxN@T8dte7u3I2krEBq3ydb/Ke3jto9owrQ5GFGnefBIeridpd4qGiEA9DWhxbeK7dz5iF0VNQmrx4ICoQLsdEZ1NPjuccTy/Th@91yug5XKooWGn3YPy26/4B)</sup>

Comment: Thnx for this explanation! Really useful and helpfull for me